# Need htaccess apache rewrite rule to remove slash in front of query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying to add a rule to my .htaccess file to remove a slash in front of any query string.
An URL like https://www.someDomain.com/someText/anotherText/?bp=someNumber should be rewritten to URL https://www.someDomain.com/someText/anotherText?bp=someNumber so there must be no slash in front of the question mark.

Thx

Comment: Trailing slash with query string, it's not the same answer (not a dublicate) !

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

For redirection with code 301

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your rule inserts the local path so i changed it to RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] which is working fine.